# How to load a irregular csv file using Rust

Tags: csv, rust

I would like to load the following csv file, which has a difference of notation rules between before 2nd line and after 3rd line.
**test.csv**

```
[YEAR],2022,[Q],1,
[TEST],mid-term,[GRADE],3,
FirstName,LastName,Score,
AA,aaa,97,
BB,bbbb,15,
CC,cccc,66,
DD,ddd,73,
EE,eeeee,42,
FF,fffff,52,
GG,ggg,64,
HH,h,86,
II,iii,88,
JJ,jjjj,72,
```

However, I have the following error. I think this error is caused by the difference of notation rules. How do I correct this error and load the csv file as I want.
**error message**

```
StringRecord(["[YEAR]", "2022", "[Q]", "1", ""])
StringRecord(["[TEST]", "mid-term", "[GRADE]", "3", ""])
Error: Error(UnequalLengths { pos: Some(Position { byte: 47, line: 2, record: 2 }), expected_len: 5, len: 4 })
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\read_csv.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

**main.rs**

```
use csv::Error;
use csv::ReaderBuilder;
use encoding_rs;
use std::fs;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let path = "./test.csv";
    let file = fs::read(path).unwrap();
    let (res, _, _) = encoding_rs::SHIFT_JIS.decode(&file);

    let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_reader(res.as_bytes());

    for result in reader.records() {
        let record = result?;
        println!("{:?}", record)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

**Version**

```
cargo = "1.62.0"
rustc = "1.62.0"
csv = "1.1.6"
encoding_rs = "0.8.31"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can correct this error by using "flexible" method.

```
use csv::Error;
use csv::ReaderBuilder;
use encoding_rs;
use std::fs;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let path = "./test.csv";
    let file = fs::read(path).unwrap();
    let (res, _, _) = encoding_rs::SHIFT_JIS.decode(&file);

    let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new()
+       .flexible(true)
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_reader(res.as_bytes());

    for result in reader.records() {
        let record = result?;
        println!("{:?}", record)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```